# How to detect at compiletime if a certain struct or function is defined at global scope

Tags: c++, c++11

I am building against ancient header files, as you do.

But, of course, I am using newer features, using various runtime checks.

The particular issue I have today is that I need to compile-time assert that the `FTS` and `FTS64` structs, as defined in `<fts.h>` (ie `/usr/include/fts.h`) are binary compatible, ie that I can treat a call through the one interface as identical to the other. Or, at least, I can on 64-bit.

Unfortunately, today, I have ancient header files (predating a "The GNU C Library" copyright claim header from 1994) that does not define `FTS64` at all, and I have to live with that for this build.

But if I were to build against the new header file, or on a new platform, then I'd like the compiler to activate these `static_assert` statements, just in case the code needs revisiting on that platform.

I can't simply assert that the type does or does not exist, thank you for your generous redirections, as ever, I had read them. It may exist, it may not exist. If it does exist then I want to assert about it. Of course, you are welcome to explain how those other techniques can be applied.

Usually, what I would hope for is a new `#define` that is contemporary with the new class and methods, then `#ifdef` with that, but no such luck.

So, what I'm looking for is some mechanism that I can use that can detect that the `FTS64` struct has been declared - or one of the methods, eg `fts64_open()`, has been declared - which can /then/ be used to mask the `static_assert`.

At the moment, the best idea I have is a triple-layer of namespaces, force-reinclude the header in the inner namespace, and declare a dummy symbol in the outer namespace, perhaps `typedef` to the `FTS` structure, or declaring it as an `enum`, then in a template perhaps, I can mask the types and do my static assert:

```
#include <fts.h>

namespace outer {
  typedef FTS FTS64;
  namespace middle {
    enum {FTS};
    namespace inner {
      #undef _FTS_H
      #undef  __BEGIN_DECLS  // yes I know! Can't get much uglier, can it?
      #define __BEGIN_DECLS  
      #undef  __END_DECLS    
      #define __END_DECLS    

      #include <fts.h>

      static_assert(sizeof(::FTS)==sizeof(FTS) , "I don't think <fts.h> was reloaded??")
      static_assert(sizeof(::FTS)==sizeof(FTS64) , "FTS64 appears to be defined, and the structure of FTS64 is not identical to FTS")
      // .. and some member offset checks as well...
    };
  };
};
```

What this is doing is declaring FTS64 as an alias of FTS by default, so the asserts all pass, but with the option of being overridden by the header.

For those who say "but glibc never had /only/ fts":

```
bash-4.1$ objdump -T /lib64/libc.so.6  | grep fts
00000000000ddc90 g    DF .text  00000000000000d4  GLIBC_2.2.5 fts_close
00000000000dee40 g    DF .text  000000000000056c  GLIBC_2.2.5 fts_read
00000000000dd980 g    DF .text  0000000000000024  GLIBC_2.2.5 fts_set
00000000000ddd70 g    DF .text  00000000000005ab  GLIBC_2.2.5 fts_open
00000000000dece0 g    DF .text  0000000000000152  GLIBC_2.2.5 fts_children
```

And from a newer build environment

```
[root@d6be84af3eb8 linux]#  objdump -T /lib64/libc.so.6  | grep fts
00000000000f1880  w   DF .text  0000000000000024  GLIBC_2.23  fts64_set
00000000000f18b0  w   DF .text  0000000000000140  GLIBC_2.23  fts64_children
00000000000f0f20  w   DF .text  0000000000000309  GLIBC_2.23  fts64_open
00000000000f1230 g    DF .text  00000000000000e8  GLIBC_2.2.5 fts_close
00000000000f1320 g    DF .text  0000000000000553  GLIBC_2.2.5 fts_read
00000000000f1880 g    DF .text  0000000000000024  GLIBC_2.2.5 fts_set
00000000000f0f20 g    DF .text  0000000000000309  GLIBC_2.2.5 fts_open
00000000000f1320  w   DF .text  0000000000000553  GLIBC_2.23  fts64_read
00000000000f18b0 g    DF .text  0000000000000140  GLIBC_2.2.5 fts_children
00000000000f1230  w   DF .text  00000000000000e8  GLIBC_2.23  fts64_close
```

Is there *any* easier way to get to there from here? Something clever with templates and `using`, perhaps? [using the autoconf engine is a good idea]

Thanks for the folks who reopened this! I think in the end this nested namespace is working for me, but if anyone does come up with a better solution, please do post an answer, otherwise I might have to tick "using the autoconf engine".

Tagging notes: `fts.h` is a C header file, but I'm coding in C++, so I'm happy to see answers in either. Use of features newer than C++11 to solve the issue is appreciated, though I can't use them right now, either. And of course, C would not be using `static_assert` I guess, but there are techniques that can generate similar compile-time errors in C.

Comment: I think you _will_ have to use your current approach (e.g. `static_assert` on `sizeof` and some member `sizeof` and `offsetof`). I wouldn't worry. Does the old code even use `FTS`? If so, just using `FTS` everywhere should be fine (or `FTS64`). You could just hack up the old code to use `FTS64` if needed. Although `struct stat` has differences based on 64 bit, it appears that the `FTS*` tried to do this, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @CraigEstey This is a "we have to do everything" drop-in library. If the client code uses fts we support fts. The unlikelihood of finding a customer using this interface is partially the reason I don't want to duplicate our existing code.

Comment: I was looking in linux [glibc] source. It has `FTS` and `FTS64`. But, freebsd _only_ has `FTS`. I don't think any fancy C++ stuff is better than `static_assert`. But, rather than trying to "figure it out" as you're doing, I'd do what `autoconf` does (with `.m4` macros and tests). Or, how about (e.g.) `#ifdef __linux__ ... #elif defined(__freebsd__) ... #else #error unsuppported OS #endif` You say [to customer]: we [only] support linux, freebsd, netbsd, openbsd, ... Then, the `#ifdef __linux__` et. al. works

Comment: @CraigEstey If you go back far enough, the glibc headers don't have FTS64 either. That's what I'm building with :-) It may be that in that ancient world fts is separate to glibc, of course.

Comment: But yes something in autoconf that detects FTS64 does not compile is certainly another option.

Comment: Thanks for the folks who reopened this! I think in the end this nested namespace is working for me, but if anyone does come up with a better solution, please do post an answer.